# Pie chart with 2 portion set label with center position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have problem regarding setting the uilabel in the middle edge in pie chart circle.

In my Pie chart there are 2 portion.
Both portion change dynamically.
How can i get center position in both portion so i can set my label in the center edge of the particular section.

Thank You

Regards,
Keyur Bhalodiya

Answer (score 0):

use carteasian equation.

```
(x,y) = (rcos@,rsin@).
```

R is the radius of the piechart. @ is the angle at which you need to find a point. In your case middle of your pie slices.